# Insert repeatedly from foreach loop

Tags: php, sql, foreach

I have a problem I'm trying to insert data into a table except that I need to retrieve the id before

```
  $get_ = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM  table
                        WHERE id = :id");
  $get_->execute(['id' =>$id]);

  $get_ = $get_->fetchAll();

  foreach ($get_member as $k) {

    $not = "INSERT INTO notifications(..., ..., ...,id)
            VALUES(:..,:...,:...,:id);
    $q = $bdd->prepare($not);

    $q->execute([
        '..' => ,
        'id' => $k['id'] // from foreach loop
    ])

}
```

I want an insertion as many times as the loop returns the result.

thank you in advance

Comment: Where does `$get_member` come from in your code? What you have could work, except I'd prepare the insert statement before the loop and just pass the parameters to it each time. But doing it as a single query would be simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using a loop for something that SQL does natively?  You should be using `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO notifications (..., ..., ...,id)
    SELECT :.., :..., :..., t.id
    FROM table t;
```

Comment: Can you explain please i never used this

Comment: @BlackosNftrois please make an effort to go inform yourself first, when you come across something you are not familiar with. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html

Comment: Thanks this worked now i have another problem. for example when I insert is that in the table where I do the SELECT that there is the same id several times how do I insert it once?      `$in = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO notifications(
    id_com,id_topic,name)

    SELECT iduser, id_topic, 'reply'
    FROM c_topic t WHERE t.id_topic = ?");

    $in->execute([$get_id]);`

Comment: You can use `select distinct` instead of `select`.